# Examples - tag.first and tag.last

Tags: python, tkinter, tags

I can't seem to find any examples.

```
text = Text(root)
text.tag_add("here", "tag.first", "tag.last")
text.tag_config("here", background="black", foreground="green")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tag.first` and `tag.last` represent the first and last character of text with the given tag.

The following block of code adds the tag "here" to a range of text (line 13 character 25, to line 13 character 35), and then uses `"here.first"` to move the cursor to the first character that has the tag "here" (ie: line 13, character 25).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text.tag_configure("here", background="black", foreground="green")

with open(__file__, "r") as f:
    text.insert("1.0", f.read())

text.tag_add("here", "13.25", "13.35")
text.mark_set("insert", "here.first")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what are the ```"13.25"``` and ```"13.35"``` meaning?

Comment: @MaiconErick: those are two indexes: line 13, character 25 and line 13, character 35.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you using this range to add the tag? I may not even have 13 lines

Comment: @MaiconErick: you may not have 13 lines, but this code does. In order to illustrate the use of `here.first`, some text somewhere had to have the "here" tag. I chose to highlight the section `"here.first"`.